# SendKeys() is adding default value (issue) + datetime value sent

Tags: jasmine, protractor

basically the issue is taking place at the moment when I send some value which is appended to a default value '01/01/2000' somehow. I've tried different ways to do this without succeed, I've used these exact lines in other script and it worked but I don't know why this isn't working here. Please find below the last code I used followed by the picture with the issue displayed.

```
  var targetStartDate = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('StartDate'));
   targetStartDate.clear().then(function () {           
       targetStartDate.sendKeys('09/01/2016');           
     })
```

[example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7UkB.png)

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1):

You can try issuing `clear()` call before sending keys:

```
targetStartDate.clear();
targetStartDate.sendKeys('09/01/2016');
```

The other option would be to select all text in the input prior to sending keys:

```
// protractor.Key.COMMAND on Mac
targetStartDate.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a"));
targetStartDate.sendKeys('09/01/2016');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this same issue before. There is an input mask formatting the input in the field. In order to solve this, you must write your test as if it were the actual user, with the formatting in mind:

```
var targetStartDate = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('StartDate'));
// Remove the forward slashes because the input field takes care of that.
var inputDate = '09012016';

targetStartDate.clear();
// Loop through each character of the string and send it to the input
// field followed by a delay of 250 milliseconds to give the field
// enough time to format the input as you keep sending keys.
for (var i = 0; i < inputDate.length; i++) {
  targetStartDate.sendKeys(inputDate[i]);
  browser.driver.sleep(250);
}
```

Depending on the latency of the site and performance, you may either need to decrease the 250 millisecond delay, or be able to decrease it.

Hope this helps!